# Images are seemingly randomly truncated when sent over sockets in python using PIL and BytesIO

Tags: python, sockets, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I want to send PIL images over a socket in python. I used a method suggested on stack overflow:

```
def exchange_image(self, img_send):
    fd = io.BytesIO()
    img_send.save(fd, "png")
    img_recv = self.exchange(fd.getvalue(), MAX_IMG_SIZE) # max size is 10000000
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_recv))
    
def exchange(self, to_send, size):
    if self.role == "client":
        self.conn.sendall(to_send)
        return self.conn.recv(size)
    elif self.role == "server":
        received = self.conn.recv(size)
        self.conn.sendall(to_send)
        return received
```

The problem with this method is that sometimes it throws a strange error which should not happen in my opinion.

```
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 0 (actual buffer size is 0)
```

which causes

```
OSError("image file is truncated")
```

The error happens when I use the returned image and make a PhotoImage out of it.

```
self.image_gui = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
```

I am unable to wrap my head around this as the buffer apparently disappears at random (one can call the function 5 times with perfect results and then suddenly it does not work anymore).
This is the first time I do "networking" and it most probably has something to do with the way I am misunderstanding the inner workings of BytesIO, send and recv. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven’t provided a [mcve], but the likely problem is that you don’t check the return value of `recv`. TCP is not messaged-based. `recv(n)` can return 1-n bytes (or zero on connection close) and you must loop until you receive the total bytes you need.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works.

```
def exchange_image(self, img_send):
    fd = io.BytesIO()
    img_send.save(fd, "png")
    img_recv = self.exchange(fd.getvalue())
    fd.close()
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_recv))
    
def exchange(self, to_send):
    size_send = str(len(to_send))
    size_send = "0" * (MAX_INIT_SIZE - len(size_send)) + size_send
    if self.role == "client":
        self.conn.sendall(size_send.encode())
        size_recv = int(self.recvall(MAX_INIT_SIZE).decode())
        self.conn.sendall(to_send)
        return self.recvall(size_recv)
    elif self.role == "server":
        size_recv = int(self.recvall(MAX_INIT_SIZE).decode())
        self.conn.sendall(size_send.encode())
        received = self.recvall(size_recv)
        self.conn.sendall(to_send)
        return received

def recvall(self, size):
    msg = bytes()
    while len(msg) < size:
        msg += self.conn.recv(size)
    return msg
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.